# How to \foreach similar commands in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

So I have this :

```
        \node [above] at (\fpeval{7/16},0.04) {\tiny $\frac{7}{16}$};
          \draw [color=red,latex-] (\fpeval{7/16},0) -- (\fpeval{7/16},0.2) ;
        \node [above] at (\fpeval{11/16},0.3) {\tiny $\frac{11}{16}$};
          \draw [color=red,latex-] (\fpeval{11/16},0) -- (\fpeval{11/16},0.4) ;
        \node [above] at (\fpeval{11/12},0.04) {\tiny $\frac{11}{12}$};
          \draw [color=red,latex-] (\fpeval{11/12},0) -- (\fpeval{11/12},0.2) ;
        \node [above] at (\fpeval{1/12},0.3) {\tiny $\frac{1}{12}$};
          \draw [color=red,latex-] (\fpeval{1/12},0) -- (\fpeval{1/12},0.4) ;
```

which draws a series of points on a number line generated in Tikz :

[image]

Is there a way to neatly write this with a \foreach?

Comment: Can you please make the code snippet into a fully compilable example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}
\tikzset{every path/.style={draw=red,latex-},
        every node/.style={above,inner sep=1pt}}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \foreach \num/\den [count=\n,evaluate=\n as \j using {isodd(\n)==1?.4:.2}] in {1/12,7/16,11/16,11/12}{
          \draw (\fpeval{\num/\den},0) -- (\fpeval{\num/\den},\j)node  {\tiny $\frac{\num}{\den}$} ;
          }
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well that count use is all kinds of brilliant.